# Date insertion in Google sheet appending ' in cell

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

To write the data into the Google spreadsheet I am using following code.

```
private static void writeValuesInSpreedSheet(Sheets service, String spreadsheetId, int sheetSize) throws IOException {
    String range = "A"+(sheetSize+1)+":K"+(sheetSize+1);
    List<List<Object>> newData = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Object> rowValues = new ArrayList();
    rowValues.add(getCurentDateInESTFormat());
    rowValues.add("2");
    rowValues.add("3");
    rowValues.add("4");
    rowValues.add("5");
    rowValues.add("6");
    rowValues.add("7");
    rowValues.add("8");
    rowValues.add("9");
    rowValues.add("10");
    rowValues.add("11");
   /* List<Object> rowValues1 = new ArrayList();
    rowValues1.add("1");
    rowValues1.add("2");*/
    newData.add(rowValues);
    //newData.add(rowValues1);
   // response.setValues(newData);


    ValueRange oRange = new ValueRange();
    oRange.setRange(range); // I NEED THE NUMBER OF THE LAST ROW
    oRange.setValues(newData);
    List<ValueRange> oList = new ArrayList<>();
    oList.add(oRange);

    BatchUpdateValuesRequest oRequest = new BatchUpdateValuesRequest();
    oRequest.setValueInputOption("RAW");
    oRequest.setData(oList);

    BatchUpdateValuesResponse oResp1 = service.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, oRequest).execute();

    System.out.println("Response Values " +oResp1.values());

}

private static Object getCurentDateInESTFormat() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdfAmerica = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
    sdfAmerica.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
    String sDateInAmerica = sdfAmerica.format(new Date());

    return sDateInAmerica;
}
```

In sheet we have defined the date and currency type of respective column.

I am able to write the data but eventually its prepending `'` in the data for example - `'09/04/2016`

Because of this we are not able to open it into date format. I have attached one screen shot as well.

[image]

We are using [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/) V4.

I am asking this question because i did not find any link/solution related to it.

Comment: Uppercase `Y' in `SimpleDateFormat` means week-year not calendar-year.

Comment: Just a guess: Try entering the data in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format (YYYY-MM-DD). Apply a format in the spreadsheet to display that value in whatever style you desire. Also, avoid the troublesome old date-time classes that are now supplanted by the java.time classes. `String output = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ).toString()`  yields `2016-01-23` style output.

Comment: Please edit your title to *precisely* summarize your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `ValueInputOption` `RAW` you need to pass dates in the [serial number format](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/concepts#datetime_serial_numbers). The Apache POI library provides a [`getExcelDate`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html#getExcelDate(java.util.Date)) method that will handle most of this for you, but you'll need to add a day to account for the difference in the [epoch used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing).